# How do I connect to Oracle SQL using VBA?

Tags: sql, oracle, vba

I'm a newbie with vba, and would appreciate help with connecting to Oracle SQL using VBA.
I have such code for MS Server, and need to modify it somehow (or create a new one) so it works with Oracle SQL.

Here's the code:

```
Public Const sConnect As String = "xxx; Initial Catalog=xxx; User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"

Sub GetData1()

Sheets(1).Range("a1:ao20000").ClearContents

Dim rsConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sQuerry As String

sQuerry = "select * from xxx"

Set rsConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

rsConnection.ConnectionString = sConnect
rsConnection.Open

Set rsRecordset = rsConnection.Execute(sQuerry)

Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsRecordset

rsConnection.Close

Set rsConnection = Nothing
Set rsRecordset = Nothing

End Sub
```

My questions are:
Do i need to install anything else than Oracle Developer? If so, what?
How to change the code to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance!!
Regards,
Maciej

Comment: assuming the code works now, then [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) should help you get connected

Comment: As Sean indicated, it mostly comes down to your connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Oracle client software on your computer.  The smallest setup is to use Oracle instant client, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html.

The only thing you need to change in your program is the connection string